# Messages starred by me can only be sorted by the number of stars

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

You can see all starred messages for a chat room and there you can filter only messages starred by you. But! The default (and only) sorting is by the number of stars a message has. But what do I care about the stars if I'm only looking for messages starred by me? Still, that's a valid sorting option. But there are no other sorting options and if you disregard the sorting by the number of stars, messages appear out of order by date.

I was just looking for a list of messages starred by me sorted by date, most recent first and the message I was actually looking for turned out to be in the far end of the last page.

I'm asking to add the sorting by date of starred chat messages.

Comment: You are assuming that there's a greater difference between no stars and one star than between one star and ten stars. Some of the users might disagree.

Comment: For me there's no difference since I'm explicitly looking for messages starred *by me*. Also what kind of list has a default sorting method not by date and doesn't allow it?