# I'd like to be able to sort starred messages by date OR number of stars

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

When you go to a chatroom's description, you can get a list of all starred posts, all posts starred by you, and all starred posts posted by you. I really like having these lists, but I would like them even better if I had the ability to sort them by number of stars or date posted, separately. Right now, there's just the default ordering, which is neither of those two.

Can we please have the ability to choose what order we want these messages arranged by? (For example: Date, # of stars, and default)

([This unanswered question from a few years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233835/messages-starred-by-me-can-only-be-sorted-by-the-number-of-stars) makes a similar feature request, but has apparently received little attention. Hopefully a broader proposal will catch the necessary devs' attention.)

Comment: One use case for this: When I've been away from a chatroom for a while, I would like to browse all the starred messages posted since I was last there, regardless of how many stars they received.